# Why can't I hit the app install button when a blue screen filter is running?

Tags: stock-android

I began using Twilight recently. Then when I tried to install an app, the install button won't click until the filter is turned off. I'm curious why this is so. Before experiencing this I wouldn't have imagined something like this would even happen.

Comment: Because [Clickjacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking) is used by various malwares as well. You supposedly installed a simple app, it created an overlay of some agreement over package installer's interface you see when attempting to install an app, and in the background you ended up clicking on "Install". The restriction you saw is a native defense mechanism. Search  [Tapjacking Android](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=TapJacking+Android)